How to make a Minecraft Villager walk to a Location?
For Minecraft, utilizing the Bukkit/Spigot API, I have a LivingEntity Villager that I would like to path, or "walk" to a Location.
I have seen some older examples using PathEntity to perform this effect, to varying degrees of success, but such methods now appear to have been removed from more modern versions of the Spigot API.
I am currently using the spigot-api-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded & craftbukkit-1.21.1 jar libraries in my build path, so I would like to find a solution that works with v1.21.1 or higher. Thank you.
